# Titanium Developer Crashes on Startup (was fine)

Tags: macos, startup, titanium, appcelerator, crash

Closed my laptop when I left work. When I got home and opened it, it had restarted. Now when I go to open Titanium Developer it instantly crashes.

So I can't even open it now. Any ideas on how to debug this or figure out what is going wrong?

Thoughts of even trying to see a message or any detailed error report would be helpful. I'm pretty new to the Mac world, I'm not even sure why my computer restarted - is there a place to see events or what may have triggered that.  Couldn't find anything on their forums about this issue.

Comment: Could you post the crash report and the console log? For console logs, go to Applications→Utilities and open Console. Crash reports can be found from Console.app; or you can directly go to (your home directory) → Library → Logs → CrashReporter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this awhile back, just realized I didn't tie up this loose end.  I actually had to reinstall the OS. One of the Os files must have been corrupted or locked.  With OS X you can reinstall the OS without reinstalling over your apps or data. So took about 30 minutes to reinstall and everything was fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same instant crash problem and found a post on http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/21121/titanium-crashing-on-startup-on-mac that suggests running this `chmod -R g+u /Library/Application\ Support/Titanium`  - so far so good.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing this in 2017 and beyond:

1. Quit Appcelerator
2. Load Terminal
3. appc logout

The Dashboard was attempting to load my cached user stats but appcelerator was rejecting my expired session. Logging out of appc solved my issue.